# Better way to map string fields to variables

Tags: c++, windows

I have some global variables that will be assigned a value once the configuration file is read.

```
bool bar1;
int bar2;
string bar3;
```

I read the configuration file which looks like below:

```
foo1 = 12
foo2 = 0
foo3 = 1
...
void func()
{
   //read file into a std::map mp
   for(auto i:mp)
   {
      if(i.first=="foo1")
         bar1 = i.second;
      else if(i.first=="foo2")
         bar2 = i.second;
      else if(i.first=="foo3")
         bar3 = i.second;
       .....
   }
}
```

I have a lot of such variables to initialize from a file. Is there a better way to do this because this will bloat my function.

PS:I am still stuck with C++03.

Comment: `PS:I am still stuck with C++03.` No you aren't ... `for(auto i:mp)` is not valid c++03. It is c++11.

Comment: Also this question is super unclear. Where do the `barX` variables come from? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe use `std::map`?

Comment: or you can use `template` and set its `typename` to `enum` of foo's.
If you use `if` or `switch`, compiler won't optimize them. but compiler will create all foo versions and store them as a long list in memory so when you need any, it'll search and pick the one for you. Please vote me if you think I'm right or else correct me.

Comment: In addition to Jabberwocky: either you map strings to pointers which become lhs in assignment. Another option would be to map strings to an enum which is in turn used in a `switch()`. You could even consider to map strings to method references.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Actually i am trying on a test environment here, but i want to make it work on older version of visual studio which does not support `C++11`. My bad, i should have mentioned this before.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox `bar1`, `bar2` are defined by me. I want to assign them value based on the values i read from a file.

Comment: @user3819404 USe the edit button and edit the question with more detail. Show how you define `barX` variables and what you expect them to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment, I elaborated a bit on the idea of Jabberwocky to use a `std::map`.

Actually, we do similar things in our S/W for configuration and similar things. The only difference – we don't use a `std::map` for this but a pre-defined array. (I didn't like the idea that something has to be done at run-time which actually never changes after compiling.) To demonstrate the concept I made a little [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  // variables
  int bar1 = 0, bar2 = 0, bar3 = 0;
  // symbol table
  const struct Entry { const char *key; int *pVar; } table[] = {
    { "foo1", &bar1 },
    { "foo2", &bar2 },
    { "foo3", &bar3 }
  };
  const size_t nTable = sizeof table / sizeof *table;
  // check that table has correct order
  assert([&]()
    {
      for (size_t i = 1; i < nTable; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(table[i - 1].key, table[i].key) >= 0) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }());
  // use table in tests
  std::pair<const char*, int> mp[] = {
    { "foo1", 123 },
    { "foo2", 234 },
    { "foo3", 345 },
    { "wrong", 666 }
  };
  // evaluate mp of OP
  for (auto i : mp) {
    const Entry e = { i.first, 0 };
    const auto iter
      = std::lower_bound(std::begin(table), std::end(table), e,
        [](const Entry &e1, const Entry &e2) { return strcmp(e1.key, e2.key) < 0; });
    if (iter != std::end(table) && strcmp(iter->key, i.first) == 0) *iter->pVar = i.second;
    else std::cerr << "Unknown var '" << i.first << "'!\n";
  }
  // print result
  std::cout
    << "bar1: " << bar1 << '\n'
    << "bar2: " << bar2 << '\n'
    << "bar3: " << bar3 << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Unknown var 'wrong'!
bar1: 123
bar2: 234
bar3: 345
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d21deb766f963c8e)</kbd>

The essential part is the `struct Entry` which groups the name of an option with the address of the corresponding variable. This could be used to store pairs of names and variable addresses in a `std::map`.

I used instead a pre-sorted array. (Sorting the keys manually in programming is not that difficult – in case of accidents the `assert()` will alert.)

In our productive S/W, we didn't use addresses of variables but method pointers to setter functions as the destination variables have varying types and the values (provide as string) are subject of a resp. parsing. However, these method pointers are compile-time solvable → the whole table can be `static`. Hence, the effort for building up the table for each function call is prevented. In this demo, the table stores addresses to local variables. This let me feel that a `static` table could be a bad idea (and I even didn't try it).

---

Upon request, here another demonstration using method pointers to setter methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class Object {
  private:
    // some member variables:
    int var1, var2;
    std::string var3;
    double var4;

  public:
    Object(): var1(), var2(), var4() { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Object &obj);

    // the setter methods
    void setVar1(const char *value) { var1 = atoi(value); }
    void setVar2(const char *value) { var2 = atoi(value); }
    void setVar3(const char *value) { var3 = value; }
    void setVar4(const char *value) { var4 = strtod(value, nullptr); }

    // the config method to set value by text    
    void config(const char *key, const char *value)
    {
      // symbol table
      static const struct Entry {
        const char *key; // the symbol
        void (Object::*set)(const char*); // the corresponding setter method
      } table[] = {
        { "var1", &Object::setVar1 },
        { "var2", &Object::setVar2 },
        { "var3", &Object::setVar3 },
        { "var4", &Object::setVar4 }
      };
      enum { nTable = sizeof table / sizeof *table };
      // check that table has correct order (paranoid - debug only code)
      assert([&]()
        {
          for (size_t i = 1; i < nTable; ++i) {
            if (strcmp(table[i - 1].key, table[i].key) >= 0) return false;
          }
          return true;
        }());
      // find setter by key
      const Entry e = { key, nullptr };
      const auto iter
        = std::lower_bound(std::begin(table), std::end(table), e,
          [](const Entry &e1, const Entry &e2) { return strcmp(e1.key, e2.key) < 0; });
      if (iter != std::end(table) && strcmp(iter->key, key) == 0) {
        (this->*iter->set)(value);
      } else std::cerr << "Unknown var '" << key << "'!\n";
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Object &obj)
{
  return out
    << "var1: " << obj.var1 << ", var2: " << obj.var2
    << ", var3: '" << obj.var3 << "', var4: " << obj.var4;
}

int main()
{
  Object obj;
  // print obj before config:
  std::cout << "obj: " << obj << '\n';
  // configure obj
  std::pair<const char*, const char*> config[] = {
    { "var1", "123" },
    { "var2", "456" },
    { "var3", "text" },
    { "var4", "1.23" },
    { "evil", "666" }
  };
  for (const auto& entry : config) {
    obj.config(entry.first, entry.second);
  }
  // print obj after config:
  std::cout << "obj: " << obj << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
obj: var1: 0, var2: 0, var3: '', var4: 0
Unknown var 'evil'!
obj: var1: 123, var2: 456, var3: 'text', var4: 1.23
```

The contents of `table` (in `Object::config()`) is `static const` and will be built at compile-time (and hopefully "burnt" into the binary). Hence, the multiple calls of `Object::config()` have the only effort of binary search of the matching `key` and calling the setter in case of success.

A essential pre-condition is that all setter methods have the same signature. Otherwise, storing them in an array wouldn't be possible as they all have to be compatible to the method pointer element in the array.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b64b4e8c2eea80af)</kbd>

Comment: So the gist is to map key names to references to appropriate variables.Right?

Comment: Yepp. (I was just about to add a little bit more explanation.) "references" -> pointers.

Comment: @user3819404 Updated a bit.

Comment: Storing function pointers sounds great as that will help parse the value read. I didn't get that compile time solvable part.Can you please explain that a bit more.

Comment: Yepp. I will extend the answer. (May take a while...)

Comment: @user3819404 Here we go: Another sample with method pointers.

Comment: Looks perfect. Thanks a ton.